# Parsing 3D XML Tile Info

Tags: php, html, css, xml, tiles

I am recreating a game (using only web languages, mind you), and for each room I have the XML for the tile placement. Parsing the XML doesn't produce the correct result, as there are not only X & Y coordinates, but also a Z.

**XML Excerpt:**

```
<NODE CLASS="tile" REF="80" X="216" Y="144" Z="38" />
<NODE CLASS="tile" REF="81" X="240" Y="144" Z="38" />
<NODE CLASS="tile" REF="82" X="264" Y="144" Z="38" />
<NODE CLASS="tile" REF="83" X="288" Y="144" Z="38" />
<NODE CLASS="tile" REF="84" X="312" Y="144" Z="30" />
<NODE CLASS="tile" REF="85" X="336" Y="144" Z="30" />
```

You can see the result of parsing this here: http://openvmk.com/parsexml.php (the tiles aren't even close to their correct positions)

The original XML is here: http://openvmk.com/banquet.xml

I need to know how to implement the Z using HTML/CSS or JavaScript (jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know how to implement the Z using HTML/CSS or JavaScript
>   (jQuery).

Assuming that "Z" is the stacking order for when tiles overlap, you're looking for the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/z-index) property.

More information is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index

Comment: No, its not the stack order, as you can see here http://openvmk.com/parsexml.php, specifying the z-index would not solve anything.

Comment: I already looked at your page, but it doesn't tell me what Z is actually supposed to be, or what you're trying to do. Are you trying to make [isometric tiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection)?

Comment: Exactly; I don't know what Z is, that's my question. Yes, I'm trying to make isometric tiles.

Comment: I recommend looking through these results: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+isometric+engine

Comment: @Nicholas Welch - I'd suggest using [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) or [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-transform)

Comment: Can you point me in a direction of understanding what Z is, I don't want someone else's premade engine. That won't answer my question.

Comment: @Yoshi The tiles will be invisible, so I see no need to skew them.. enlighten me?

Comment: I don't know what Z is because I don't know what game you're trying to recreate, or what the game looks like, or what you're trying to make it look like, or where you got that XML file from. If it is an isometric game, it's *probably* the "elevation" of the tile. Look at the images here: http://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/absolute-isometric-depth-sorting/

Comment: @Nicholas Welch Can you explain what you want to do with the tiles in the end? Also: `...understanding what Z is...` I'd guess z is the z-axis in a 3D space.